# Facebook App Limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, policy

Does Facebook limits the number of applications that I create?

At the moment, I have only five applications created and I am getting this error
message when try to create a new one:

> App creation failed
>
> Please use your personal account to create this
> app. To use a different name for testing, create the app with your
> personal account and then create a test account.

Comment: The error states that you are not creating the app from your personal or user Facebook account but instead through one of your test users or a business account. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes @AnveshSaxena, I've created an new account, but I already confirmed this account with phone number. How I make this account "personal"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit on how many applications you can create through your Facebook account.